# Sum amount associated with item in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
country   letter             keywords                 amount
   c         y     ['fruits', 'apples', "banana"]       700
   c         y     ["music", "dance", "banana"]         150
   c         y     ['loud', "dance", "apples"]          350
```

I'd like to sum the amount associated with each keyword.
Note: `country` and `letters` are not always the same, as in the contrived data above. Also, the list of `keywords` vary in size.

I've tried several solutions. I've attached my fastest one below. I've also tried solutions with `apply` and `defaultdicts`...

```
keywords_list = []
for i in zip(*[df[c] for c in df.columns]):
    data = list(i[0:2])
    for k in i[2]:
        row = [k] + data + [i[-1]]
        keywords_list.append(row)

df_expanded = pd.DataFrame(keywords_list)
df_expanded.groupby(list(range(3)))[3].sum().reset_index()
```

---

**Goal**

```
  country letter keywords  amount
0       c      y   apples    1050
1       c      y   banana     850
2       c      y    dance     500
3       c      y   fruits     700
4       c      y     loud     350
5       c      y    music     150
```

**Edit: corrected error in example of goal**

---

**Data**

```
country = list("ccc")
letters = list("yyy")
keywords = [['fruits', 'apples', "banana"], ["music", "dance", "banana"], ['loud', "dance", "apples"]]
amount = [700, 150, 350]

df = pd.DataFrame({"country" : country, "keywords": keywords, "letter" : letters, "amount" : amount})
df = df[['country', 'letter', 'keywords', 'amount']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.keywords.values.tolist())
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename('keywords')
print (df1)
0    fruits
0    apples
0    banana
1     music
1     dance
1    banana
2      loud
2     dance
2    apples
Name: keywords, dtype: object

print (df.drop('keywords', axis=1).join(df1).reset_index(drop=True))
  country letter  amount keywords
0       c      y     700   fruits
1       c      y     700   apples
2       c      y     700   banana
3       c      y     150    music
4       c      y     150    dance
5       c      y     150   banana
6       c      y     350     loud
7       c      y     350    dance
8       c      y     350   apples
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.set_index(['country','letter','amount'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.keywords.values.tolist(), index = df.index) \
        .stack() \
        .reset_index(name='keywords') \
        .drop('level_3',axis=1)
print (df1)
  country letter  amount keywords
0       c      y     700   fruits
1       c      y     700   apples
2       c      y     700   banana
3       c      y     150    music
4       c      y     150    dance
5       c      y     150   banana
6       c      y     350     loud
7       c      y     350    dance
8       c      y     350   apples
```

Then need `groupby` with aggregating `sum`:

```
print (df.groupby(['country','letter','keywords'], as_index=False)['amount'].sum())
  country letter keywords  amount
0       c      y   apples    1050
1       c      y   banana     850
2       c      y    dance     500
3       c      y   fruits     700
4       c      y     loud     350
5       c      y    music     150
```

**Timings**:

```
In [47]: %timeit (df.set_index(['country','letter','amount']).keywords.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_3',1))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.55 s per loop

In [48]: %timeit (jez1(df3))
10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit (jez2(df3))
10 loops, best of 3: 29.7 ms per loop
```

Code for timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df.copy()
df4 = df.copy()                

def jez1(df):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.keywords.values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('keywords')
    return df.drop('keywords', axis=1).join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)

def jez2(df):
    df = df.set_index(['country','letter','amount'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.keywords.values.tolist(), index = df.index).stack().reset_index(name='keywords').drop('level_3',axis=1)
    return df1
```

Thank you [`MaxU`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522249/sum-amount-associated-with-item-in-a-column-of-lists/40522333?noredirect=1#comment68286265_40522333) for improvement with [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) - then another `drop` is not necessary. Unfortunately `timing` failed (`KeyError: 'keywords'`), so I cannot compare it.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is MUCH better. But i think we can improve it even a little bit more: `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('keywords').values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('keywords'))`

Comment: @MaxU - thank you for improvement. `pop` is rarely used, but here it is good idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [76]: (df.set_index(['country','letter','amount'])
    ...:    .keywords
    ...:    .apply(pd.Series)
    ...:    .stack()
    ...:    .reset_index(name='keywords')
    ...:    .drop('level_3',1)
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[76]:
  country letter  amount keywords
0       c      y     700   fruits
1       c      y     700   apples
2       c      y     700   banana
3       c      y     150    music
4       c      y     150    dance
5       c      y     150   banana
6       c      y     350     loud
7       c      y     350    dance
8       c      y     350   apples
```